# 'reweigh' percentages by probability?

Tags: probability, bayesian, percentage

Suppose 3 tv shows may choose any of 150 low-ranking guests , 1 president and 8 high-ranking guests for each show, but they don't have to choose any of those guests at all. They may determine themselves if and how many of the guests they want to have on the show.

Show A airs 100 times, show B 40 times, show C 200 times a year.

```
Show A chose 10x a high-ranking guests,20x a low-ranking guests, 1x the president 
Show B chose 10x high-ranking, 5x low-ranking, 1x president
Show C chose 5x high-ranking, 2x president
```

which can be summarized in a datatable:

```
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+
| Show |  Guest    |  Totalguest | TotalShows | ChosenGuests |
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+
| A    | High      |           8 |        100 |           10 |
| A    | Low       |         150 |        100 |           20 |
| A    | President |           1 |        100 |            1 |
| B    | High      |           8 |         40 |           10 |
| B    | Low       |         150 |         40 |            5 |
| B    | President |           1 |         40 |            1 |
| C    | High      |           8 |        200 |            5 |
| C    | Low       |         150 |        200 |            0 |
| C    | President |           1 |        200 |            2 |
+------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------------+
```

**Goal:** I would like to get insights into the preferences of shows for choosing a guest and quantify this while taking into acount all of the info on #guests, TotalShows, ChosenGuests.

I have been playing around with renomarlizing (ChosenGuests/TotalShows) * (Totalguest/(8+150+9=159)) to the total percentage of guests per show (e.g. for showA: 31%, showB: 16%, showB: 7%), which illustrates the relative preference of guests for each show, but then I do not know exactly what the units are? I feel like there should be a very simple way to do it correctly in a way so that it is scientifically sound.

Answer (score 0):

> **Goal:** I would like to calculate a number reflecting the preferences of the shows for choosing a guest correcting for #guests
>   and MaxShows.

So you are interested in some kind of regression model that predicts number of chosen guests (e.g. Poisson regression), or probability of choosing a guest (logistic regression). Parameters for shows would be the "numbers reflecting the preferences" and regression will deal with "correcting" for the other parameters. Now you need to make a decision what kind of model suits your purpose better and what variables to include.

One thing to notice is that you have a colinear variables:

- `Totalguest` has always the same values for each level of `Guest`,
- `TotalShows` has always the same values for each level of `Show`.

What it means for you is that you *cannot* include `Totalguest` together with `Guest`, or `TotalShows` together with `Show`, since they "duplicate" the information they contain. You need to decide for using only one of each pair.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that I think I need number per show-guest. I have restated it. Would perhaps something more descriptive suite better?

Comment: @tafelplankje what do you mean by "number per show-guest"?

Comment: like, an extra column for datatable that has the percentages (ChosenGuests/TotalShows) corrected for the 'probability' of choosing the certain guest (e.g. high-ranking = 8/159) and #TotalShows.Basically I would like to get insights into the preferences of shows for choosing a guest and quantify this while taking into acount all of the info on Totalguests, TotalShows, ChosenGuests. So I could rank the preference and see which shows invites which guest, compared to each other.

Comment: @taleplankje so this is what logistic regression would estimate.